# Specflow: Can some step definitions be used feature wide?

Tags: specflow

When a feature requires some given steps, you need to specify for each scenario "Given I have done something And something else And the last thing...". Doing all those steps for every scenario can be tedious.

One solution could be to specify all this in one Given step (Given I am set up to test feature X). However, it's not something very precise while reading the feature steps.

This is why I'd like to know if step definitions can be used feature wide. I'd use something like this :

> Feature: My feature
>
> ```
> Obvious feature description here.
>
> Given I have done something
> And something else
> And the last thing
> ```
>
> Scenario: Y validation
>
> ```
> When I type X
> Then I should see Y
> ```
>
> Scenario: Z validation
>
> ```
> When I type X
> Then I should see Z
> ```

Over this :

> Feature: My feature
>
> ```
> Obvious feature description here.
> ```
>
> Scenario: Y validation
>
> ```
> Given I have done something
> And something else
> And the last thing
> When I type X
> Then I should see Y
> ```
>
> Scenario: Z validation
>
> ```
> Given I have done something
> And something else
> And the last thing
> When I type X
> Then I should see Z
> ```

Any solution is welcome, but I'd like something that can be understood while reading the .feature file, instead of having to dig in the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a great and easy solution to your problem in Gherkin, the language used to write feature files. It's called Background and is a couple of steps that is executed before each scenario in the file.

See this wiki page for more information; https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Background

Comment: Exactly what I needed. 
Strangely enough, I did not see background used in examples I looked at. It is in the documentation though. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When using the Backgroung tag your scenarios and feature will look more or less like this:

```
Feature: My feature
     As a person
     I want to do something
     So that something can happen

Background: My Background
Given I have done something
And something else
And the last thing

Scenario: Y validation
      When I type X
      Then I should see Y

Scenario: Z validation
      When I type X
      Then I should see Z
```